# White space above the UI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a Xamarin.Forms application and when I launch the application in Windows 10 mobile running build 14393 I saw extra white space instead of battery and other indicator.

Comment: Not sure what your actual question is: You've shown no screenshots, no code... nothing. Please edit your question with more info, before this question ends up being closed as *unclear what you're asking*.

Answer (score 0):

1. you must include Windows Mobile Extension for the UWP into Windows UWP project.
2. Modify OnLaunched of App.xaml.cs of Windows UWP Project, and add following:

   ```
       if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
       {

           var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
           if (statusBar != null)
           {
               statusBar.BackgroundOpacity = 1;
               statusBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
               statusBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
           }
       }
   ```